# How to find ArrayList length after filtered in apache royale

Tags: actionscript-3, mxml, apache-royale

This code snippet is from TDJ List

```
<j:Card>
   <html:H3 text="Jewel List"/>
   <j:List id="list" width="200" height="300" dataProvider="{simple}" change="onChange(event)"/>
            <j:TextInput width="200">
                <j:beads>
                    <j:TextPrompt prompt="filter list..."/>
                    <j:SearchFilterForList list="{list}"/>
                </j:beads>
            </j:TextInput>
            <j:Label id="selected" html="{describeItem(list.selectedItem)}"/>                               
</j:Card>
```

There is j:SearchFilterForList

What i want to know is when its work (type some text on the filter textbox), how to find filtered list length?

Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Just use the new "`length`" property just recently added. Tour de Jewel was updated as well showing the use of this new bead property in the List examples.

```
<j:Label html="{'list filtered length: ' + filter.length}"/>
<j:TextInput>
    <j:beads>
        <j:TextPrompt prompt="filter list..."/>
        <j:SearchFilterForList id="filter" list="{iconList}"/>
    </j:beads>
</j:TextInput>
```

Notice that the filtering performed by this bead is only visual, and the underlaying dataProvider is not filtered itself. To get a filtered view of the dataProvider you should use `ArrayListView` API, that is similar to *flex* `ListCollectionView` with `filterFuncion`.

Comment: Carlos, it worked.
But when i modify your code and trace filter length why the returned value is undefined?

    <j:Label html="{'list filtered length: ' + filter.length}"/>
    <j:TextInput localId="txtSearch" change="txtSearch_change(event)">
       <j:beads>
          <j:TextPrompt prompt="filter list..."/>
          <j:SearchFilterForList id="filter" list="{iconList}"/>
       </j:beads>
    </j:TextInput>

    private function txtSearch_change(event:Event):void
    {
      trace("[Filtered Length]", filter.length); //this filter length returned "undefined"
    }

Comment: Hi, just tried this on code and test and I'm getting the right number and not undefined. I think something in your code could be causing this problem?